# Accelarating image processing algorithm on GPU, parallel processing Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, vectorization, gpgpu

I want to accelerate my algorithm because I need to run it on hundreds of images,so I tried to use unvectorized GPU code, running the same code on GPU, I have nvidia Geforce GT 650M with 2 GB on my PC, however it was very slow than the CPU version. After searching I am convinced to pass to vectorized GPU code using batch process (pagefun, bsxfun), I tried so much to solve this problem without a solution. can someone help me about this code:

```
Q=100;
       for i=3:n-2
        for j=3:m-2 
         A(i,j)=0;
            for c=1:Q
                        if B(i,j,c)~=0
                        A(i,j)=A(i,j)+(-(B(i,j,c)).*log(B(i,j,c)));
                        end
            end
        end
       end
```

Another question Why Matlab uses just 20% of my CPU? How I can take benefits of my CPU to accelerate my processing

Is Matlab a single threaded app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectorized version is this:

```
BB = B(3:(n-2),3:(m-2),:);
cutoff = 10^(-6);
logBB = log(BB);
logBB(BB<cutoff) = 0; % remove divergent terms
A = -sum(BB.*logBB,3);
```

This should already run much faster even on a CPU. If you have a GPU, all you need to do is have the input array

```
BB = gpuArray(BB);
```

stored on the GPU, and then collect the results

```
A = gather(A);
```

back to the CPU

Comment: Doesn't gpuArray still need parallel computing toolbox?

Comment: Yes, the parallel toolbox is required for gpuArray

Comment: Thank you very much Airidas Korolkovas, however I didn't got a great improvement in time of execution, the use of pagefun can improve the time or not? I have the parallel toolbox. nvidea GT 650M

Comment: Unfortunatelly the gpuArray() approach has quite a bit of overhead and for your type of problem you are likely to see maybe 2-3x speed-up only for large inputs with more than 10^5-10^6 elements. You may get more speed-up by using arrayfun(), but it will only be effective if a lot of elements are zero and thus can be aborted after B=0 check. I would guess that the fastest approach is to write a custom CUDA kernel, here is a tutorial: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/accessing-advanced-cuda-features-using-mex.html

Comment: unfortunately this vectorized version doesn't work because each element of  B(i,j,c) must not be a zero to avoid the NaN case when computing the log. I tried adding epsilon to BB than eliminating the negative sign numbers

Comment: Sorry, the problem was Inf*0 = NaN; I have given a better version in the edited answer.

Comment: @Airidas Korolkovas thanks again for fast reply, I tried this in several data but always I get A=0

Comment: I have tried this 
   { BB = b(3:(n-2),3:(m-2),:)+10^-6;
    A = -sum(BB.*log(BB).*(BB~=10^-6),3);A=double(uint8(A));}

Comment: Do you have negative values in B?

Comment: No the values of B are normalized [0,1] the result of the A may take negative values

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this method still outperform my classical one, I gained about 10 seconds for each image, with video of 5000 images it is a great difference

Answer (score 0):

You will need to buy the [parallel computing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/). (using parfor).

This is a well known limitation of matlab where some of the underlying functions do not paralellize across multiple cores (not threads). A quick ballpark is to look at how much CPU matlab uses and multiply that by the number of COREs you have in your pc (this should get you to somewhere around 100%).

If you want to utilize your computers GPU, parallel computing toolbox is the only way to do so.

From [mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22172-how-to-fully-use-the-cpu-of-my-pc)

> This really depends on what you are doing. For some code MATLAB can only utilize a single core of a single processor, for other code, MATLAB will automatically utilize all available cores (and maybe processors). It really depends on the underlying functions. Some things cannot be easily parallelized. Sometimes you can help MATLAB with things like parfor loops. Other times you might need something like MPI. Still other times there really is nothing you can do.

Comment: This is not completely correct, you can open several instances of MATLAB, and each will work on a different core.

Comment: Great point! Just requires you to change up your code and split your loops.

Comment: If one's plan to use `parfor` and such, one's code should be written in a way that enables him splitting the loops quite easily. Otherwise, _parallel computing toolbox_ won't help him...

Comment: Another problem when trying to use `parfor`  is to change the variables inside the loop to sliced data

Comment: So what would you recommend for parallelizing matlab assuming you don't own the parallel computing toolbox